# Подсветка определенных слов в TextView или WebView

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, textview

Есть текст в текстовых документах с расширением *.txt. Текст через буфер грузится в `TextView` или `WebView`, но он одинаковый. Интереса не вызывает. Поэтому решено добавить подсветку слов.

Можно ли составить некий *.xml файл, в котором прописать зависимость цвета от слова. К примеру, 
// цвета указаны условно

```
cos(), red

sin(), red

ans(), blue

dif(), green

и так далее.
```

А в `TextView` или `WebView` указать ссылку на этот файл, чтобы `java` код форматировал весь текст.
[описал условие очень примитивно. Скорее всего некоторые моменты не существуют в `java` / `xml`]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разделите задачу на части:

1. Формирование данных-условий.
2. Парсинг этих данных в формат ключ-значение.
3. Применение данных к форматированию текста.

Сделать можно так:

1. Составляете файл в формате (например) [`JSON`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).
2. [Парсите](http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/) его в (например) [`Map<String, String>`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/hashmap.php)
3. В строке находите и заменяете нужные слова `html` тегом `font`:

   ```
   String str="cos() бла-бла cos()";
   String wordToColor="cos";
   String color="#145A14";
   str=str.replaceAll(wordToColor, "<font color="+"\""+color+"\""+">wordToColor</font>");
   ```

И теперь надо указать `TextView` что надо отображать `html`:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Comment: А, если в каждом текстовом документе содержатся абсолютно разные слова ? Пока все просто в виде текста, без `html` тегов. В `html` я перевел только один документ для тестирования.

Comment: Если честно, то я не понял, что вы хотите сказать.

Comment: Простите, написал и не проверил предварительно код. Все работает. Нужно только подправить `wordToColor = "cos"` и в `str = str.replaceAll(wordToColor, "<font color=" + "\"" + color + "\"" + ">" + wordToColor + "</font>");`. С `JSON` и `Map<>` еще не разбирался, буду гуглить, читать, вникать. Ваш ответ отмечаю как лучший! // Если есть пара ссылок на норм источники о `json` и `Map`, то добавьте их, пожалуйста, также в обновленный ответ. Еще раз спасибо за быстрый ответ!

Comment: Добавил ссылок.

Comment: Увидел. Спасибо! Хорошего дня! :-)